# What is tuner amperer and will it fix issue with radio?

Tags: brakes, audio, mazda, cx7

I'm not sure if that's how you spell it, but the Mazda technician said "tuner amperer".

In any case, I recently went to a Mazda dealer because there was radio static every time I hit the brake. This was most noticeable with stations with a weak signal. This is the question: [Active brake lights interfere with radio station on ‘16 Mazda CX-5?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/71995/active-brake-lights-interfere-with-radio-station-on-16-mazda-cx-5)

The Mazda dealer blamed the antenna, even though I had a hunch that it wasn't the issue. It turns out that it wasn't the antenna.

They're still diagnosing the issue, but the Mazda technician says it could be the "tuner amperer". He says it's a mass of cables in the car. According to the dealer, this part costs over USD$1,000.

What is this so-called "tuner amperer" and could that be the issue?

Comment: I'm going to guess that he said and you misunderstood or he mispoke and the correct term is "tuner amplifier".  Many vehicles have a separate module from the "head unit" in the dash that has the actual audio electronics in it.  I suspect this may be where they are looking.

Comment: @jwh20 - Sounds like an answer to me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that he said and you misunderstood or he mispoke and the correct term is "tuner amplifier". Many vehicles have a separate module from the "head unit" in the dash that has the actual audio electronics in it. I suspect this may be where they are looking

Comment: Do you think this may be the reason for the static while hitting the brakes?

Comment: Yes, that could very well be the reason.